# How does rollback() in JDBC Template work?

Tags: java, spring

I am learning JDBS template and wonder if there is a way to rollback operation.

It is easy to do it using JDBC, just

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
// DoinП stuff
con.rollback();
```

But is there a way do the same using JDBS template?

Comment: How are you doing your transaction management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc/2.4.4) like in this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/)

Thanks to this `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` and to the spring boot autoconfiguration mechanism, a [jdbc template](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7aabd8bf2d401504636bfe6ce00e57ea8ac7d473/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JdbcTemplateConfiguration.java#L39) bean and a [transaction manager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.java#L59) bean will be created for you.

Then you can use `@Transactional` annotation on non private method to wrap your code into a transaction :

```
@Transactional
public void methodA() {
  jdbcTemplate.update(...);
  jdbcTemplate.update(...);
}
```

or you can use a [transacionTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) to handle the transaction programatically

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

  private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

  public SimpleService(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
  }

  public void methodA() {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<>() {
      public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(...);
        jdbcTemplate.update(...);
        return jdbcTemplate.query(...);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: JdbcTemplate is from spring JDBC, Spring data JDBC uses @Repository as the rest of Spring data members.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute multiple statements and want to be sure all or none executed, you can use transactions.

- First, you have to create a session and begin the transaction.
- After, you can execute statements and commit the transaction.
- But, in case of problems, you can rollback (undo previous statements).

With spring you can use @Transactional annotation

```
@Transactional
public void transaction() { // Spring will begin transaction
   doTransactionalStatements(); // Spring will rollback in case of RuntimeException
} // Spring will commit transaction
```